# Datalist not displaying properly in Edge and IE11

Tags: angular, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge, html-datalist

In my .html I've a  to assign some value and a datalist with 2 option :

- The first : to take the value of my input
- The second : where I *ngFor a list of values.

```
<input autoComplete="off" 
type="text" 
(change)="methodWhenIChangeMyValue()">
      <datalist id="{{row.MYOBJECT}}">
            <option value="{{value}}">{{value}}</option>
            <option *ngFor="let i of arrayToParse[row.MYOBJECT]" value="{{i.MYOBJECTID}}">
                    {{i.MYOBJECTID}}</option>
       </datalist>
</input>
```

In Firefox and Chrome my list displays normally, but in Edge/IE11 only one element is displayed. 
All data are loaded, but I need to navigate inside my option to show them. 
Finally, when I've all my element (after a navigation) if I search an element more specific a grey block is displayed.
How can I fix this ?

All my actions for < input > are not refered inside this snippet.

Only one element is displayed at the beginning:

[image: One element, but all loaded]

A grey block is displayed when I search a more specific value:

[image: Grey block when I search more specifically]

Comment: I suggest you check the source code when it shows the grey box. Looks like it is showing empty elements in it. It can be caused by any CSS code or due to any other code. With your above sample code, we are not able to produce the issue. I suggest you post a sample code that can able to produce this issue. It can help us to check and test the issue.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a bug within MS Edge (**Microsoft Edge 44.17763.1.0, Microsoft EdgeHTML 18.17763**), I was able to reproduce it using the following steps:

1. Launch the following demo: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist
2. Type out the word 'Chocolate' letter by letter in the 'Choose your flavour' input, then erase all the characters, one by one, until none left. What appears is a broken datalist underneath the input, like the screenshots above.

Answer (score 0):

Datalist is not supported by all browsers and it is not handled the same way. I recommend you switch to something such as flexselect: https://rmm5t.github.io/jquery-flexselect/

You can find many other alternatives out there, but this is the one I use since it doesn't have any compatibility issues.